# How to formulate and solve optimization problem with pulp in python

Tags: python, pulp

**Inputs:**

- 2 lists of variables, list_1 and list_2.
- function that takes an element from each of lists and return some value >=0:
  foo(el_list1, el_list2)
  we could assume that we have a matrix of the shape (len(list_1), len(list_2)) that has values >=0.

**Task:**
Find pairs of elements of list_1, list_2 that give maximum sum of foo(el_list1, el_list2), given that each element of each list could be used only once.

**Example:**

- list_1 = [l1_0, l1_1, l1_2]
- list_2 = [l2_0, l2_1, l2_2, l2_3]

```
A = 
[[0.0, 1.5, 2.4, 0.8],
 [3.1, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 1.3, 2.5, 1.0]
],
where A[i, j] = foo(list_1[i],list_2[j])
```

For this example result could be something like:

- max sum = 3.1 + 1.5 + 2.5 + 0 = 7.1
- pairs that give this sum:
  [(l1_1;l2_0),(l1_0;l2_1),(l1_2;l2_2),(None,l2_3)]

Answer (score 0):

```
from pulp import *

model = pulp.LpProblem("_problem", LpMaximize)

A = [[0.0, 1.5, 2.4, 0.8],
 [3.1, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 1.3, 2.5, 1.0]
]
        
# Creates a list of all the supply nodes
list1 = ["I0", "I1", "I2"]

# Creates a list of all demand nodes
list2 = ["J0","J1", "J2", "J3"]

# The cost data is made into a dictionary
Acosts = makeDict([list1,list2],A,0)

Routes = [(w,b) for w in list1 for b in list2]

pv = LpVariable.dicts("Route",(list1,list2),0)

# Objective
model += lpSum([pv[w][b]*Acosts[w][b] for (w,b) in Routes])

# Because you don't have any constraints, I made it up. 
for w in list1:
    model += lpSum([pv[w][b] for b in list2])==1

for b in list2:
    model += lpSum([pv[w][b] for w in list1])==1
    
model.solve()
print("Status:", LpStatus[model.status])
for v in model.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
print("Maximize Cost = ", pulp.value(model.objective))
```

output:

```
Status: Infeasible
Route_I0_J0 = 0.0
Route_I0_J1 = 1.0
Route_I0_J2 = 0.0
Route_I0_J3 = 0.0
Route_I1_J0 = 1.0
Route_I1_J1 = 0.0
Route_I1_J2 = 0.0
Route_I1_J3 = 0.0
Route_I2_J0 = 0.0
Route_I2_J1 = 0.0
Route_I2_J2 = 1.0
Route_I2_J3 = 1.0
Maximize Cost =  8.1
```